# Youtube API key quota exceed before ever using the key in question

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have a simple request to get videos from a youtube channel:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20

The key I was using ran out of quota, so I decided to make a new one, the problem is that, even though I've never used it, I still get the following erro:

> "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e."

I'm very confused as to why this is happening. I created the new key the same way I did with the last one, but it just won't work. I'm shure I'm doing some stupid mistakes here.

Comment: Did you created the second key bound to the same Google project as the first key is?

Comment: oh... yes. That makes a lot of sense. That was probalby my mistake, I didn't even realised that. Thank you.